# AEM Touch UI - input number - how to?

Tags: dialog, aem

I need to add to my touch-ui dialog a input field with numberInput like this
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/coral-ui/docs/2.17.0-granite-004/number-input.html
but I don't find documentation.
Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by adding a similar node like below to `_cq_dialog/.content.xml`

```
<quantity
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    fieldLabel="Quantity"
    name="./quantity"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield" />
```

Here is the full documentation of number field: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield/index.html

Comment: jcr:primaryType will be nt:unstructured, touch UI doesn't use jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"

Answer (score 1):

There is a `sling:resourceType` already available OOTB for that - `granite/ui/components/foundation/form/numberfield` .

If you need reference implementation look at OOTB image component dialog - `/libs/foundation/components/image/cq:dialog/content/items/column/items/size/height`